# Simple problem with MAX in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the table with rows:

```
ID          CountryCode Status
----------- ----------- -----------
2           PL          1
3           PL          2
4           EN          1
5           EN          1
```

and by the query

```
    SELECT [CountryCode]
      ,MAX([Status])
  FROM [TestTable]
  GROUP BY CountryCode,Status
```

I want to get:

```
CountryCode Status
----------- -----------
PL          2
EN          1
```

but I get:

```
CountryCode Status
----------- -----------
EN          1
PL          1
PL          2
```

What is wrong with this query?

Best regards

**EDIT**

Ok, Thanx for manz answers, but I didn't add part of query, which is :

```
Having Status != 3
```

so I think I must use Status in group by :/

Script to create and fill table:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CountryCode] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
          ( CountryCode, Status )
  VALUES  ( 'PL', -- CountryCode - nvarchar(2)
            1  -- Status - int
            )

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
          ( CountryCode, Status )
  VALUES  ( 'PL', -- CountryCode - nvarchar(2)
            2  -- Status - int
            )

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
          ( CountryCode, Status )
  VALUES  ( 'EN', -- CountryCode - nvarchar(2)
            1  -- Status - int
            )
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
          ( CountryCode, Status )
  VALUES  ( 'EN', -- CountryCode - nvarchar(2)
            1  -- Status - int
            )
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the filter for rows status <> 3.  If you don't want to include them at all, then you could add it as a where clause, where status <> 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get rid of the group by status.  The group by says return a new row for every unique combination of CountryCode **and** Status, which is not what you want.

You can add the where clause to exclude the rows that you don't want to consider in your query.

Try:

```
SELECT [CountryCode]
      ,MAX([Status])
  FROM [TestTable]
  WHERE status <> 3
  GROUP BY CountryCode
```

Answer (score 2):

Just drop status from the group by:

```
   SELECT [CountryCode]
      ,MAX([Status])
  FROM [TestTable]
  GROUP BY CountryCode
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add `group by status` it will do additional grouping within country code. Then your MAX selects maximum for country code. Remove `status` from group by.

Answer (score 0):

Don't group by the Status.  Try this:

```
SELECT [CountryCode]
      ,MAX([Status])
  FROM [TestTable]
  GROUP BY CountryCode
```